# Can sagemaker's linear learner be used for multiclass classification?

Tags: algorithm, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I am building a multiclass classifier on aws Sagemaker, and would love to use the predefined linearlearner algorithm for classification.

Comment: please also add the code you tried for, and what you want.

Comment: @GautamRai, I just want to know if the linear learner can be used for multiclass classification. because in the documentation it is written that it can be opened in 2 formats: 1. binary classifier 2. regressor

Comment: Linear learner, by its name, is learning a line. The line can either be used to calculate a value on it or split into two (binary) groups. If you want to have multiple classes you can create multiple models with class-i/Not-class-i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible now.

You can set the predictor_type hyper-parameter to `multiclass_classifier`.

See the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ll_hyperparameters.html.